# Howto display exceptions from android real device

Tags: android

I'm new at developing for Android.
I tried to develop in emulator, but it is incredible slow, so the fastest for me is to run my app on real device Huawei G525 with Android 4.1.2. I'm also new at Java, so I make a lot of beginner mistakes, so I really need to see all the exceptions thrown in my app.

I use Android Studio 0.3.2 and when I click on Debug button and choose my Huawei Device, the application runs if it is correct, but anytime when there is some error it stops with **Unfortunately, ... has stopped** and it should throw exception (eg. when I call method on non object)

The only interesting Error I see is **E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)**.
Developer options in my phone

- Protecte SD card disabled.
- USB debugging enabled
- mock location enabled (tried also without)
- Enbale traces selected all  (tried also without)

In my manifest file debugging=true

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.radekzilka.gwexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        ...
```

Can anybody tell me, howto display exceptions thrown in my app in my phone?

Comment: you can use try and catch and log the error into logcat or using break point and trace how your code work and here article your explain you how to debug on real device and emulator 
http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/index.html

Answer (score 1):

As for the **E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2).** its irrelevant to your application crash and you will see it very often, dont worry about it.
as for logging or hunting your exception try to use the TRY-CATCH around your problematic codes

```
Try
{
    ... some code you think might be causing the exception...
} 
Catch ( Exception E )
{
     log.e ("Error Log", E.getMessage()); // for exact error cause
     // or alternatively instead of the above line you can use this
     E.printStackTrace(); // for the whole error stack including the actual cause
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm surprised that it doesn't log uncaught exception by default. Like when I run applet I see the Exception in console, when I run some Java desktop application I usually can also see it in some error output (console).
Can't I turn it on somehow? Or where should I put this try/catch so it displays all uncaught exceptions in all activities?